# What functions need to be redefined in class A in order for its instances to implement the context managers protocol?

Tags: python-3.x

I found this question on the web but it does not contain an answer.
Am I correct if I say the answer is:

**enter**() method = returns the resource that needs to be managed
**exit**() method = does not return anything but performs the cleanup operations

I would really apreciated it if somebody could confirm that this is the right answer

Comment: Yes - https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types